# duplicate row, adding role, based on flags

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 8 columns containing flags Y/N.
I wish to duplicate rows, selecting all non-flag columns and adding a role column value (different for each flag column, for example equal to the column name itself), but only create a row for that role if the corresponding flag value is Y.

I wish to avoid doing union 8 times.
I was looking at a connect by clause but cannot figure out how to use that.
How can this be done without using unions?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mention of "connect by" suggests that you are using Oracle.  If so, you can unpivot using a lateral join:

```
select t.*, f.which
from t cross join lateral
     (select t.flag1 as flag, 'flag1' as which from dual union all
      select t.flag2 as flag, 'flag2' as which from dual union all
      . . . 
     ) f
where flag = 'Y';
```

Comment: Works all fine! thank you - first time I hear about the cross join lateral - glad to learn something new!